# KUbuntu Screenlock crashes on 17.10 since update

Tags: kubuntu, kde, laptop, plasma

Since around a month my screen locker crashes on KUbuntu 17.10, requiring  me to unlock via VTerminal `loginctl unlock-sessions`.
I've an hybrid laptop with intel & nvidia.
Problem occurs either way and shouldn't crash with intel even more because this also affects sleep mode.

Any ideas ? Ask if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KUbuntu 18.04 magically fixed this issue.
Lockscreen works now on nvidia & intel GPUs, suspend doesn't randomly crash KSM server anymore.